# Jail elements inside <DIV>?

Tags: html, xhtml, css-position, css

I am going to design a webpage, which contains `<div>`(s) that allow users to submit their (X)HTML with CSS, and being inserted into those `<div>`(s).

I understand it will suffer from XSS seriously, so I will use HTML Purifier to sanitise the (X)HTML and CSS. For instance, I will definitely not allow `<script>`, `<iframe>`, and external resources. But I wish to allow almost all other tags and CSS attributes.

Here comes the question. I wish to keep client elements (visually) inside the `<div>`(s). I have tried a partial solution, by using `position: absolute;` and `overflow: hidden;`, as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

div#jail {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;

  border: 1px dotted red;
  height: 200%; width: 50%;
  left: 25%; top: 25%;
}

/* All client's CSS is ensured prefixed with div#jail */
div#jail .client_code {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="jail">
  <p class="client_code">elements being jailed</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

So far, I have successfully jailed `<p>` inside `div#jail` for most kinds of client's HTML elements and CSS, except `position: fixed;`.

That is, if users use CSS `position: fixed;`, their elements could breakthrough the jail:

```
div#jail .client_code {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

So, is it ok to **only** block `position: fixed;`, and the jail would be tough and valid?

If there are any other ideas/design to achieve this, any solutions are welcomed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your title is attractive :)

Comment: @cHao, client's CSS will be added the prefix `div#jail`. So it would become `div#jail body div#jail { overflow: visible; }`. And `<body>` and `<html>` tags will not be allowed in client's code (as they doesn't make sense inside DIV).

Comment: Yeah...i'd reread the post and noticed that :)  Wondering, though: how thoroughly are you parsing the CSS?  In particular, the selectors?  Would i be able to say `+ div` or the like, which would select stuff outside #jail?

Comment: Thanks for reply and thanks for interest! Let's solve this together :)

Comment: This will cause so many headaches. Are you sure you want to allow HTML? BBCode or Markdown would seem much more appropriate. If you are going with HTML, I'd use a whitelist instead of a blacklist. Are you going to block javascript attributes like `onmouseover`? Otherwise the user can do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/W6PLQ/).

Comment: @MrLister, Merry Christmas and Thanks very much! Yes I am going to use a white list of HTML, as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) sanitise elements by a white list. i want to allow certain JS operations through my_custom_codes, like [xhr:getUserName]. Thanks for spotting `onmouseover` is dangerous. With only HTML and CSS, do you think only block `position: fixed;` is enough?

Comment: @cHao, Thanks for your reminder of `+ div`. I have missed your revision, and i have missed also users may use `+ div` to mess up with things outside the jail. It seems this will really cause so many headaches... :D